# deepToString method in Arrays class

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I was curious on what deepToString was actually doing so I went to look at the method.  My specific question is what does multiplying 20 by the array object length actually accomplish?

```
 public static String deepToString(Object[] a) {
    if (a == null)
        return "null";

    int bufLen = 20 * a.length;
    if (a.length != 0 && bufLen <= 0)
        bufLen = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder(bufLen);
    deepToString(a, buf, new HashSet<Object[]>());
    return buf.toString();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a performance bet. It initializes the StringBuilder with a size that has good chances to be large enough to concatenate everything without having to resize the buffer too many times (or at all), and not too large in order to avoid wasting too much memory.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, makes sense.